# How to repeat a function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, background, repeat

This is the code that I've been working on, which makes the background color flicker colors. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to make this repeat so that the background continues to change colors on and on and on.

```
var a = new Array("ff", "ee", "dd", "cc", "bb", "aa", "99", "88", "77",
                  "66", "55", "44", "33", "22", "11", "00", "00", "11",
                  "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88", "99", "AA",
                  "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "ff");

x = 0;

var b = new Array("ff", "ee", "dd", "cc", "bb", "aa", "99", "88", "77",
                  "66", "55", "44", "33", "22", "11", "00", "00", "11",
                  "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88", "99", "AA",
                  "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "ff");

x = 0;

var c = new Array("00", "11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88",
                  "99", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "ff", "ff", "ee",
                  "dd", "cc", "bb", "aa", "99", "88", "77", "66", "55",
                  "44", "33", "22", "11", "00");

x = 0;

function bg_eff() {
  col_val = "#" + a[x] + b[x] + c[x];
  document.bgColor = col_val;
  x++;
  if (x == 32) {
    clearInterval(change_bg);
  }
}
change_bg = setInterval("bg_eff()", 50);
```

Comment: You have to promise to pass me the bong if I help you with this.

Comment: @Pointy: LOL! That's so true!

Comment: @yeee Use `["a", "b", "c"]` instead of `new Array("a", "b", "c")`

Comment: @Gert G wow that makes me feel funny just looking at it

Comment: @yeee Also `setInterval(bg_eff, 50)` instead of `setInterval("bg_eff()", 50)`

Comment: Uaaah! **Please** promise not to put this on a real webpage!

Comment: of course ~meng~ ... wish i could pass you more than the bong haha. Thanks a lot. New at this stuff but i keep coming back here

Answer (score 5):

```
x = (x + 1) % 32;
```

Also, you should remove the `clearInterval` (and associated if), and there is no need to use a string for the `setInterval`:

```
change_bg = setInterval(bg_eff, 50);
```

Comment: @yeee to be clear, see that code where it says `if (x == 32) ...`? you would take that out and put in the code that @Mathew Flaschen suggests here

Answer (score 3):

modified code here (using jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/S8g6k/1/

I use a recursive setTimeout instead of the interval, it's more resilient that way (if your function takes longer than the interval nothing odd occurs)

Comment: @thejh Of course, not. `x++; if (x==32) { x=0; }` is obviously more readable than `x=(x+1)%32;`. It's twice as long, but more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
x += 1;
if ( x === 32 ) { x = 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Matthew's answer but since the arrays are in the same sequence, you could do something like this.

```
var a = new Array("ff", "ee", "dd", "cc", "bb", "aa", "99", "88", "77", "66", "55", "44", "33", "22", "11", "00", "00", "11", "22", "33", "44", "55","66", "77", "88", "99", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "ff");  // one array
var x = 0;  // var for not global (even though in this context it still is...)
function big_eff() {
    col_val = "#" + a[x] + a[(x + 5) % 32] + a[(x + 10) % 32]; // or whatever spacing you want
    document.bgColor = col_val;
    x = (x + 1) % 32;
    setTimeout("big_eff()",50);  // setTimeout baby!
}
```

Comment: THANKS!! I stepped out for a little bit and came back to see this. It's really great.

Answer (score 0):

a new version with pure Jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/S8g6k/5/

I use .animate for much cleaner code (no need for the arrays or the x++)

oh and warning: scary color swaping

```
$("body").css("background-color","#ffff00");
var bg_eff;
(bg_eff = function(x)
{
   var duration = 1600;
   if(x)
   {
       $("body").animate({backgroundColor:"#0000ff"},duration,function(){
           bg_eff(false);
       });
   }
   else
   {
       $("body").animate({backgroundColor:"#ffff00"},duration,function(){
           bg_eff(true);
       });
   }
})(true);
```

Comment: You should declare bg_eff. Replace `(bg_eff = function(x)` with `var bg_eff = (function(x)`.

Comment: good point, updated.  It does need to be global to function in the lamdas, but it should at least be explicit.